# Maximum integer usage in C#

Tags: c#, memory, heap-memory

I'm about to use Data.Annotations library and [Range(1, int.maxValue)] attribute. I'm warring about **int.maxValue usage**, because I will have many such attributes per class, and I don't want to **add to memory** int.maxValue every time I invoke this.

I have a guess that it will be not duplicated values, because **int is a structure**, and CLR will store only a link to a value in heap. Am I right?

Comment: No, it's the opposite: value types (structures) are always copied by value. But we're only talking about 4 bytes there, you don't have to worry about memory usage from attributes...

Comment: Thanks! So, every time I call int.MaxValue - I will allocate additional 4 bytes in heap, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, every time I call int.MaxValue - I will allocate additional 4
>   bytes in heap, right?

Actually it allocates memory when you give `int.MaxValue` as argument to the whole attribute. Since value types are passed by value they're copied instead of creating a reference to the same object.

```
public void X(int a)
{
}

X(int.MaxValue); // copy, copy, copy, copy!
```